# How can I add standard fields to a standard API in SAP without using Eclipse?

Tags: abap, hana, cds, abap-adt

I have a standard API where I have to add 2 standard fields in SAP. I don't have access to Eclipse.

Can anyone help me regarding this? I am new to this concept.

I asked for Eclipse access but I was informed that there is no need for it. My process was to get the standard CDS view and use extend view and add those 2 fields.

Comment: I guess you are talking about using the old SAP GUI-based IDE (`SE80` and others). For many modern technologies, Eclipse ADT is the only possible solution, like maintaining CDS views.

Comment: I don't know what kind of "standard API" it is, but your question seems more about maintaining/extending CDS Views, so it should reflect in the title, rather than the very generic term "API".

Comment: The nice thing about standards in SAP is that there are so many to choose from. Which kind of "Standard API" do you mean?